# npTDMS Python Module not getting all channel properties

Tags: python, numpy, labview

I'm using the npTDMS Python module for reading TDMS files, and I'm having trouble getting all the channel properties. I can open my TDMS file using Scout or DIAdem or even the built-in LabVIEW viewer, and I can see that each channel in the file (Time and Pressure) has four properties: NI_ArrayColumn, NI_ChannelLength, NI_DataType, and name. However, the following code only outputs

```
OrderedDict([('NI_ArrayColumn', 1)])
```

The code is the following:

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile

tdms_file = TdmsFile("2017-10-16;12.37.05_Pressure (1).tdms")
channel = tdms_file.object('Scan', 'Pressure')
print(str(channel.properties))
```

Where are the other three properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the `npTDMS` module does not handle properties generated on-the-fly the same way the built-in LabVIEW viewer, Scout, DIAdem, and the Excel add-in do. This seems a bug to me, so I have an [issue reported on the github](https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/issues/87).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the following snippet answers your question (maybe the bug has already been corrected), but I've found that the npTDMS module works fine when retrieving on-the-fly-generated group properties.

```
##Importing necessary packages.
import numpy as np
import nptdms

##Opening TDMS file.
file = nptdms.TdmsFile(my_file)

##Gets all file objects (group entities); each 'key/value' pair comprises a path and an object pointing to a group on the file.
fileObjs = list(file.objects.items())
##For each object (group), the written properties are retrieved and listed. The indexing is set to skip the root group.
for i in range(1, len(fileObjs)):
    list(fileObjs[i][1].properties.items())

############################################################################
############################################################################

##Or, using list comprehension:
for propValueTuples in [list(fileObj[1].properties.items()) for fileObj in list(file.objects.items())[1::]]:
propValueTuples
```